# Does damage to a worker impact the time it takes to complete an improvement?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

Due to the [Miasma](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Miasma_%28CivBE%29), many of my units in the early game take light damage if simply because its difficult to see what tiles have Miasma (lol).   Before the research of Alien Biology, which grants workers immunity to Miasma, a [worker](http://civilizationbeyondearth.gamepedia.com/Worker) can take a few random dings of 10% damage.
[image: worker]
So that got me wondering, does damage have any impact on a workers performance?

Is there a benefit beyond survivability to fully healing a worker before starting improvements?

Comment: I hover the mouse over any squares that I'm not familiar with to see if Miasma is present. Then all of the qualities of that tile appear next to my world map, which will display all of the attributes for that tile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The health of a worker has no effect on its construction speed.

It is still better to keep your workers at full health. Certain improvements, especially those which involve removing forests first, can take several turns. A low health worker can end up being killed by miasma before finishing the improvement.

If you're having trouble seeing miasma, it's also a bad idea to have workers walking around with low health- just in case you accidentally move into miasma and die.